# How to OneToOne with field non-existing column on DB

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have two tables. I want to join both but there is no joint column between them. To generate joint column, i added new field on my `cell` entity. Field name is `cityCode`, which is created by `lac` column substring index 1 to 3 then converted to int. So actually when you check DB you cant see `cityCode` column. I didnt store it on DB.

I have `city` entity also and it has id column which is name `cityCode` also.
I want to join tables with `cityCode` columns.

Here is my json list

- `cell` entity : https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=a5ed0c0ab0c249f89c9360ecca3f0750
- `city` entity : https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=205565db82014c75b292122f141239c8

I code non-existing column by using code below. it works well as u see it on my `cell` entity json.

```
    @Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @Column(name = "LAC", insertable =  false, updatable = false)
    private Integer cityCode;

    public Integer getCityCode()
    {
        return Integer.parseInt(lac.substring(1,3));
    }
```

I try to use code below it throws error.

```
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "cityCode")
    private  City city;
```

oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-00904: "GCELL6900X0_"."CITY_CODE": invalid identifier

its looking CITY_CODE column on DB so i know why it throws error but i couldnt found any solution.

Comment: Maybe `@JoinFormula` is what you need here? https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/JoinFormula.html

Comment: ``@JoinFormula`` uses sql query and column is not exists on db so it will not work. I tried ``@Transient`` i couldnt solve yet.

Comment: ??? `@JoinFormula` based on substring of LAC column. TBH your question is confusing and it is not clear exactly what columns exist in the database. You could even use  a virtual column if your database supports that. Edit your question to be about the problem you wish to solve and not your proposed solution. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem